# Failed to load <resource>: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, trumbowyg

I'm getting this error in my console when I try to load my .svg icons from my S3 bucket:

```
Failed to load https://<my_bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/Trumbowyg-master/dist/ui/icons.svg: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://<my_site>.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: have you configured cors in s3 console?

Comment: No I have not....I've just had a quick search about it and my S3 UX doesn't show the option to enable it: https://i.imgur.com/2UTbaYY.png | in this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html in step 3 it gives the option. Any idea  why?

Comment: it seems like your accessing permissions of this particular svg only. Go to your bucket permission - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your S3 console
2. Click your bucket name
3. Go to "Permissions"
4. Go to "CORS Configuration"
5. Configure your CORS rules, here you have an example with wildcard(*) origin - you can use your own origin and desired methods, and **save** changes.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <CORSRule>
       <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
       <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
   ```